# Send Forms issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I'm developing an application on asp.net.I use the standard modelbinder
I have code

```
@model  Sciencecom.Models.Billboards1
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateBilboard";
    SelectList owners = new SelectList(new SciencecomEntities().Owners.Select(m=>m.Name).ToList());

}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Bilboard", "Data", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.ValidationMessage("Error")
        @*владелец*@


        <input type="text" name="Locality" value="345"/>
        <input type="text" name="Locality" value="3435" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Добавить" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            }
```

I send form on controller.but i have issue .I have reference-null

```
    public ActionResult Bilboard( IEnumerable<Sciencecom.Models.Billboards1> Billboard, IEnumerable<Sciencecom.Models.Surface> test)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

what ideas?

Comment: You don't bind any of your Model properties to your Form. Your POST method (it should be marked with an `HttpPost` attribute) should have the same type of Model as is included in your page/form.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your form you have only 2 input fields with the same name (`Locality`) which is quite confusing. So on your server all you can get is a variable with the same name as your input field because that's the only information that is posted back when the form is submitted:

```
public ActionResult Bilboard(Locality locality)
{
    ...
}
```

In the code you have shown in your question your `Bilboard` action seem to be taking some `Billboard` and `test` collection arguments but they are not present as input fields inside your form so you cannot possibly expect them to be populated.